# Uploadify fails in Firefox when anonymous access is disabled and Windows authentication is enabled

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, uploadify

I have a really slick implementation of uploadify working great in IE, FF and Chrome however when I disable anonymous access and enable Windows authentication in IIS it fails in FF throwing the 'aaaHTTP:undefined' error. My FF version is 19.0.2.

Its a classic ASP implementation, any help would be great!

Thank you in advance

Comment: There's a known bug in uploadify with Firefox - it's to do with uploadify using Flash - see 
http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/43/using-sessions-tricking-basic-authentication/p1

Comment: Thank you for the link.  After reading it I suspect back in 2009 this problem was evident however I believe its fixed now. I suspect my current issue id different.  FF is a nice to have but not essential for this project.  I plan to try and  solve this in the near future, I am thinking its an authentication/permissions related problem when the file system object is poking around the directory structure...

Comment: It's hard to see how a browser specific problem could have anything to do with Classic ASP - which is server side code.  FileSystemObject can only see the directory structure on the server.  Uploadify uses a mixture of Flash and JavaScript on the client side, and Firefox is generally the most prone to js problems in my experience

Comment: yes I realize ASP does not have browser related issues.  I thought perhaps the 500+ lines of ASP code in the ASP version of uploadify may be telling the JS to throw the 'aaaHTTP:undefined' error for some ASP FSO related problem.  Perhaps im off the mark, it was just a suspicion.